# Reference Variable internals

Tags: c#

I am confused about the reference variable in C#,Java,Javascript etc.
How can I see the details of the reference variable?
Means:In c# or Java If we declare

```
Person P=new Person();
```

what P will contain, the memory address or something else?
In Javascript we can not access the memory so what P Conatins if we declare in Javascript Person P=new Object()?

Answer (score 5):

It's up to the implementation. The value of `P` *could* be just an address - or it could be something different. For example, the Oracle JVM on a 64-bit machine is able to use ["Compressed oops"](https://wikis.oracle.com/display/HotSpotInternals/CompressedOops) in some cases to store a reference in 32 bits, while still using a 64-bit address space.

Fundamentally, a reference is simply a way of *navigating* to an object's real data. The details of whether it's a simple address, an entry into a lookup table or something else are almost never useful to a developer in the higher level language. (Obviously they're relevant to a JVM developer, but that's a different matter.)